# What does mesh size mean?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

So I want to make myself clear about the terms regarding the mesh for numerical methods. For example, if for a 2D Laplace equation, I try to divide both boundary (of same width) into 10 equal parts, then do we say 10 is the mesh size or something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that, in this case, the mesh size is
$$
\frac{\text{length of the segment}}{10}
$$

Comment: I see. Then how can we describe the "10"?